# Why spontaneous emission?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermal-radiation

From what I have understood Einstein somehow deduced the A and B coefficient for spontaneous respectively stimulated emission to match the observed blackbody radiation/Planck spectrum. How did he come to this conclusion that there should be emissions that are spontaneous? What causes that all emissions aren’t stimulated but it is necessary to invoke spontaneous emissions? Of course I know that it is not the case and most of the photons around us were caused by spontaneous emissions, but I don’t understand the fundamental/mathematical reason for it. How do we know that there aren’t enough „photons/phonons“ there of the right frequency to be causing stimulated emission for all emissions? Why is it therefore necessary to invoke spontaneous emission to be able to describe the black body radiation?

Answer (score 5):

If stimulated emission was the only radiative emission process then objects in thermal equilibrium would be transparent.

Any absorption of a light beam would be exactly balanced by stimulated emission that is in phase and in the same direction as the incident radiation. The absorption coefficient, which is the true absorption minus the stimulated emission would be zero.

A blackbody must absorb all radiation incident upon it, and the ratio of emission to absorption coefficients should equal the Planck function. If the absorption coefficient is zero then clearly that isn't possible.